# Finding Missing Orders in a Column with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Given the following table 'Orders':

```
+--------------------------+
| id|order|country|cstm_id |
+--------------------------+
| 1 |O-1  |DE     |1       |
| 4 |O-2  |AT     |2       |
| 5 |O-3  |DE     |2       |
| 6 |O-5  |AT     |2       |
| 8 |O-6  |DE     |3       |
| 10|O-10 |DE     |3       |
| 11|O-11 |AT     |3       |
| 12|O-123|DE     |1       |
+--------------------------+
```

There are values missing from both the id column and the order column.

I was successful in using this code to find missing values in id:

```
select start, stop from (
  select m.id + 1 as start,
    (select min(id) - 1 from orders as x where x.id > m.id) as stop
  from orders as m
    left outer join orders as r on m.id = r.id - 1
  where r.id is null
) as x
where stop is not null;
```

With results as wanted:

```
+------------+
| start|stop |
+------------+
| 2    |3    |
| 7    |7    |
| 9    |9    |
+------------+
```

However I have hit a roadblock on how to do the same with the order column, as the sequence is non-numerical.

Comment: Your current query could be rewritten to be more efficient using window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your  first query can be simplified using window functions (and most likely it's going to be faster as well):

```sql
select id + 1 as start, 
       next_id - 1 as stop
from (
  select id, 
         lead(id) over w as next_id,
         lead(id) over w - id as diff
  from orders
  window w as (order by id)
) t
where diff > 1;
```

The same approach can be used for the "order" value after cleaning out the non-numerical part:

```sql
with clean_ids as (
  select regexp_replace("order", '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int as order_id
  from orders
) 
select order_id + 1 as start, 
       next_id - 1 as end
from (
  select order_id, 
         lead(order_id) over w as next_id,
         lead(order_id) over w - order_id as diff
  from clean_ids
  window w as (order by order_id)
) t
where diff > 1;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/NTIEG85119

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial letter of the order number can be other than 'O' use can use regexp to split the alpha and numeric portions and sort on each portion.

```
with orders (id,order_num,country,cstm_id) as
     (values
             (1 , 'O-1'  , 'DE' ,1)
           , (4 , 'O-2'  , 'AT' ,2)
           , (5 , 'O-3'  , 'DE' ,2)
           , (6 , 'O-5'  , 'AT' ,2)
           , (8 , 'O-6'  , 'DE' ,3)
           , (10, 'O-10' , 'DE' ,3)
           , (11, 'O-11' , 'AT' ,3)
           , (12, 'O-123', 'DE' ,1)
    )
select *
  from orders 
 order by regexp_replace(order_num, '^([A-Z]+)-(\d+)$','\1') 
        , regexp_replace(order_num, '^([A-Z]+)-(\d+)$','\2')::integer ;
```